file.getParents() fail when called by non-domain user
file.getParents().hasNext() in an Apps Script fail running in the context of a "User accessing the web app".
function doGet() {
  var file_id = '1GYEyaak1AuQ8oxU7Po2FFjaNCdBl05qxg-PWyOO4orY';
  var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(file_id).getParents();
  console.log("getParents().hasNext(): " + parents.hasNext());
  console.log("getParents().next().getName(): " + parents.next().getName());
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("DONE");
}

the logs:
Jun 8, 2024, 10:13:16 AM    Debug   getParents().hasNext(): false
Jun 8, 2024, 10:13:16 AM    Error   Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end.
    at doGet(Code:5:59)

The folder and the file are both in MyDrive and shared with "Anyone on the internet with the link can edit (sign in required)" as Editor
What I was expecting
I called file.getParents() and expected .hasNext() to return true. All files must have a parent.
What I tried
I called the same code on a deployed app from a domain user and then it worked fine.

Is it team drive? "Try this api" at the bottom here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/get Set fields to * and fileId to the correct fileid and see if you are able to get the parents without using oauth(as a anonymous user)

@TheMaster  the file is in MyDrive. I followed your suggestion and used the "Try this api" app with the same results. The "parents" field was empty for a non-domain user (so a gmail user in this case).

It maybe a permission issue. How about with oauth(Check Oauth with drive scope)?
